# Getting change color with mouse hover to work using Angular

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

http://codepen.io/Feners4/pen/KggAwg

I want to get the cubes to change color with mouse hover using Angular. Ive managed to get it to work on one side of a cube, but I want the effect to change the whole cube color.

This is my HTML:

```
<header>
  Angularity
</header>

<h1>hjskl</hi>

<body>
  <div class="container" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
            </div>
  </header>
<div class="wrap">
    <div ng-app="App" class="cube"change-background colorcode=¨#FE0883¨>
        <div class="front">AAA</div>
        <div class="back"></div>
        <div class="top"></div>
        <div class="bottom"></div>
        <div class="left"></div>
        <div class="right"></div>
    </div>
</div>

</header>
<div class="wrap2">
    <div class="cube2">
        <div ng-app="App" class="front2" change-background colorcode=¨#FE0883¨>AAA</div>
        <div class="back2"></div>
        <div class="top2"></div>
        <div class="bottom2"></div>
        <div class="left2"></div>
        <div class="right2"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My JS:

```
angular.module('App', [])
  .directive('changeBackground', ['$animate', function($animate) {
    return {
      restrict: 'EA',
      scope: {
        colorcode: '@?'
      },
      link: function($scope, element, attr) {
        element.on('mouseenter', function() {
          element.addClass('change-color');
          element.css('background-color', $scope.colorcode);
        });
        element.on('mouseleave', function() {
          element.removeClass('change-color');
          element.css('background-color', '#fff');
        });
      }
    };
  }])
```

How can I get the cubes to Change color on Mouse hover to work and when Mouse leaves it changes back?

Comment: Why not use CSS for :hover handling?

Comment: I strictly want to use Angular for learning purposes.. @campino2k

Comment: *Note:* I think you are confused about `ng-app`. It's what defines the root element of your angular application and you should have only one, only the first one will work. Generally it's placed in the `body` or `html` tag.

Comment: I placed it on my `body` tag, but now no color change occurs on mouse hover.. @SpencerWieczorek

Comment: @feners It's due to invalid HTML which needs to be fixed. Along with that the controller will throw an error if it wasn't defined. See my answer below for more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the main problems here is how you defined `ng-app`, as I've stated in my comment this defines the root of the application to be used by Angular. Placing it in such a specific location would mean none of the other elements are connected to Angular. The first thing that needs to be done is your HTML should be cleaned up, there are duplicate closing `header` tags with no openings and there is not a closing `body`. Since you never defined a controller and it's not being used I removed it (*otherwise it will throw an error*) After that you can just define your `ng-app` on the `body` and that will allow to use your directive on any element:

```
<html>
<header>
  Angularity
</header>

<h1>hjskl</hi>

<body ng-app="App">
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="cube"change-background colorcode=¨#FE0883¨>
        <div class="front">AAA</div>
        <div class="back"></div>
        <div class="top"></div>
        <div class="bottom"></div>
        <div class="left"></div>
        <div class="right"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="wrap2">
    <div class="cube2">
        <div class="front2" change-background colorcode=¨#FE0883¨>AAA</div>
        <div class="back2" change-background ></div>
        <div class="top2" change-background></div>
        <div class="bottom2" change-background></div>
        <div class="left2" change-background></div>
        <div class="right2" change-background></div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation on this. It was very helpful! It worked.. Thanks!